# lunching app with one click vs two click android

Tags: android

I want to create an android app that runs different activities based on how many times you click the starting icon.

Once you have deployed your app if you click just one time in the icon the app starts and show one activity,
if you click two times in the icon to run the app it should show another different activity.

The goal of this is if there are no settings in the app, the setting activity should popup
the next time. If the setting have been done, then the app can start. Double click would reopen the setting activity if you want to change the setting.

Comment: You mean icon on the Android home screen or icon in your app?

Comment: U cant track how many times the app is being opened. U can just check if it is opened or not.

Comment: AFAIK most, if not all, launchers do not support double clicking icons. You'd also have to factor in that HTC, Samsung, Sony, Google, LG etc all have their own launchers, not to mention Nova, Apex, Smart launchers etc. I don't know if this can be done at all, but I'm not 100% sure on this.

Comment: Forgive me, but this is lousy design and not in accordance with the Android design patterns.  Just give them access to preferences in the app menu like every other app.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but let me try to explain the idea. i want to create an app that when you click on the home screen of android make a direct call to a specific number that you can set up within preferences. so the first time yourun the app you check if pref are setted and if not you can pop up the setting activity. the second time you run the app, conf has been done so you make a direct call with the Intent.action_CALL. the problem is how to change the conf as the app start to call immediately when you click on it. so my idea was to click twice to open again preferencies

Comment: another idea is to have 2 apps, one that runs the direct call i have already it and the other one that make conf. problem is how the directcall app can read configuration done by the config app